# Join Table with Null Values

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

When i try to get one data with single schedule all result with null values appear but when i select multiple schedules the null values are gone. I want to show the null values.What's wrong?

```
SELECT SS.ID
       ,PS.ProductID
       ,PS.Parameters
       ,PS.Specification
       ,ISNULL (RD.Result,'N/A') as Result
       ,SS.DFA
FROM ProductSpecification as PS 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SR.SpecsID,SR.ID FROM StabilityResult as SR JOIN ProductSpecification as S ON S.ID = SR.SpecsID WHERE S.ProductID = 1757) as R ON R.SpecsID = PS.ID OR (R.SpecsID is NULL AND PS.ID is NULL) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT D.ResultID,D.ScheduleID,D.Result FROM StabilityResultDetails as D WHERE D.ScheduleID = 131) as RD ON RD.ResultID = R.ID OR (RD.ResultID IS NULL AND R.ID IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT S.ID,S.DFA FROM StabilitySched as S WHERE S.ID=131 ) as SS ON SS.ID = RD.ScheduleID OR (SS.ID IS NULL AND RD.ScheduleID IS NULL) 
WHERE PS.ProductID=1757 
GROUP BY RD.ScheduleID,PS.ProductID,PS.Parameters, PS.Specification, RD.Result,SS.DFA,SS.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As StabilitySched was the main table for which you opt to get other details you need to start from that table and left join other tables to get desired results. Hope the below query will produce desired results,

```
SELECT SS.ID,R.ProductID,R.Parameters,R.Specification,
     ISNULL (RD.Result,'N/A') as Result,SS.DFA
FROM StabilitySched SS
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT D.ResultID,D.ScheduleID,D.Result FROM StabilityResultDetails
) RD ON SS.ID = RD.ScheduleID
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT SR.SpecsID,SR.ID,PS.ProductID,PS.Parameters,PS.Specification 
   FROM StabilityResult SR 
   JOIN ProductSpecification PS ON SR.SpecsID = PS.ID
   WHERE PS.ProductID = 1757
) as R ON RD.ResultID = R.ID;
```

And here we don't need group by as we are not doing any aggregate operations like count/sum,... And no need of specifying is null conditions in joins as it will do by default.

Hope it helps!